# How do computer-controlled machines fit into the site's scope?

Tags: discussion, faq, on-topic, questions

Hand crafting includes the use of tools.  All kinds of hand tools are on-topic.  Even large stationary, motor-driven tools, like woodworking shop tools, are on-topic; the crafter is controlling things and doing the crafting.  Modern sewing machines often have fancy stitches controlled by an internal computer, but the person is still the one manually controlling the over all process.

Computer-controlled machines have a fundamental difference.  The user is not directly, hands-on controlling the action.  They create a computer program or file that describes the result they want, and set up the machine.  They can then walk away and the machine does all of the actual crafting.  The user's contribution and skill is in computer use and machine setup, not hand crafting.

It has similarities to contracting out the job, where the person defines in a computer document what they want, and someone else does the actual crafting.

**How do computer-controlled machines fit within the scope of a site focused on hand crafting?**

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not intended as an exhaustive description of what is on- or off-topic. Rather, it is intended to describe the logic that applies, to aid in evaluating specific cases.

Computer-controlled machines straddle the line for the scope of the site; some aspects are on-topic and some aren't.  What the machines do is not hand crafting in the sense intended by the scope of this site.  However, they are becoming more common as an integral part of hand crafting workflows.  Computer-controlled machines are often used to make components, molds, fixtures, decorations, or other items that get used in handmade crafts, sometimes enabling projects that would not be practical without them.

- These machines are on-topic because they are often used as part of a hand-crafting workflow.  But questions and answers would not change based on how the result gets used later.  So it is **not** a requirement that each question must pertain to use of the result in a hand-crafted item.
- Going back to the example in the question of contracting out the job, on questions specific to the crafting of the item, it doesn't matter who is doing the work.  But it would be off-topic to ask questions about the contracting process, or how to solve problems with your word processing software encountered while writing the contract.  Those kinds of issues don't directly relate to what the site is about.  Similar rationale applies here.
- Like any other crafting tool, both machine usage and the elements of its care (preventive and corrective maintence) that are normally carried out by the end-user are on-topic.
- Types of questions that would be on-topic for other kinds of crafting tools would generally be on-topic for these.
- Guidelines similar to other tools apply for tangential questions that aren't specific to the actual crafting of an item. For example, identifying the right kind of machine to accomplish a specific objective is on-topic.

**Examples of what aspects would not be on-topic:**

Similar to other tools:

- **Modifying the machine** to change its design capabilities or features (this does not refer to things like swapping manufacturer-supplied parts that implement other design features).
- **Repairs that would typically require service at the factory** or repair facility.  Only the kinds of minor repairs that are routinely done by the end-user would be on-topic.

Somewhat unique to computer-controlled machines:

- **Solving computer problems or using tangential software.** Using the software that drives the machine in its operation is on-topic. Very general questions about preparing the patterns or similar task definitions might be on-topic. But questions like how to use the software that prepares the pattern, or help solving computer problems is too far afield from handmaking crafts.
- **Industrial machines.**  To the extent an on-topic question is the same as might be asked about a small "hobbyist" device, it is on-topic.  But keep in mind that this is a community of artists and hand crafters.  Questions should be ones you would expect a typical practitioner in such a community, who uses a hobbyist device, to be able to answer.

Comment: This seems pretty exhaustive, I think, and like a great initial overview for the next 100 questions!

Answer (score 0):

It seems simple. Technical questions that involve the machine/computer/software do not belong on site (at this point anyway) while questions of design, materials, aspects of the problem that are not technical would be.

Comment: It's hard to have the machines on-topic but exclude technical questions about the machine. I'm not sure there's a need to treat those machines differently from "on-topic" machines to the extent they get the same kinds of questions.

Comment: Yeah. I hear that. But then you get into the minutia of different brands of the machines. What if we have an expert one type of machine but not others, than we wind up supporting one manufactured product and excluding others. Those questions seem better directed toward the machine's support line and not Arts&Crafts.